# How can I make a linux module load another module?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel

I have the task to program one module to store some data and another module to control the first one, been able to load/unload it from the code.

I'm and kernel programming ignorant but i've tried hard to find the way to do this. Is there any function to do this?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [request_module](http://www.gnugeneration.com/books/linux/2.6.20/kernel-api/re538.html) to load a module

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to make it work. Is there some equivalent to unload?

Answer (score 1):

You usually wouldn't make one module load another, instead using the kernel's dependency system to load your prerequisites on demand. otherwise use `request_module` as suggested by Matias Valdenegro.

Comment: I know, this is just a kernel programming assignment I have to do. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Oh, i found it! release_module